# HOW to Show Exam Wise Marks by transposing Columns as Rows in Mysql Report

Tags: mysql

I have a 3 tables like :
1) Tbl_subjects

```
      +----+------+-------------------+
      | id | C_Id |     subject       |
      +----+------+-------------------+
      |  1 |   13 | తెలుగు             |
      |  2 |   13 | हिन्दी              |
      |  3 |   13 | ENGLISH           |
      |  4 |   13 | MATHEMATICS       |
      |  5 |   13 | PHYSICAL SCIENCES |
      |  6 |   13 | BIOLOGY           |
      |  7 |   13 | SOCIAL STUDIES    |
      +----+------+-------------------+
```

2) tbl_masterexam

```
      +------+-----+--------------------+
      | exid | Cid |        exnm        |
      +------+-----+--------------------+
      |   64 |  13 | Unit Test-1        |
      |   65 |  13 | Unit Test-2        |
      |   66 |  13 | Quarterly Exams    |
      |   67 |  13 | Unit Test-3        |
      |   68 |  13 | Half yearly Exams  |
      |   69 |  13 | Unit Test-4        |
      |   70 |  13 | Pre - Public Exams |
      +------+-----+--------------------+
```

3) tbl_Cmarks

```
+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| Cid | Examid | rollno | subId | Marks | paper |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     3 |    21 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     1 |    18 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     2 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     4 |    23 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     5 |    11 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     6 |    11 |     1 |
|  13 |     64 |      1 |     7 |    22 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     3 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     1 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     2 |    19 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     4 |    22 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     5 |    10 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     6 |    10 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     7 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     65 |      1 |     7 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     1 |    75 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     2 |    89 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     4 |    80 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     5 |    45 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     6 |    42 |     1 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     7 |    89 |     1 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     3 |    41 |     2 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     3 |    35 |     3 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     4 |    40 |     2 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     4 |    45 |     3 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     3 |    40 |     2 |
|  13 |     66 |      1 |     3 |    41 |     3 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     3 |    16 |     1 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     1 |    19 |     1 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     4 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     5 |    10 |     1 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     6 |    10 |     1 |
|  13 |     67 |      1 |     7 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     1 |    45 |     2 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     1 |    40 |     3 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     2 |    75 |     1 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     5 |    40 |     1 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     6 |    42 |     1 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     7 |    40 |     2 |
|  13 |     68 |      1 |     7 |    40 |     3 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     3 |    19 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     1 |    19 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     2 |    18 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     4 |    20 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     5 |    12 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     6 |    11 |     1 |
|  13 |     69 |      1 |     7 |    15 |     1 |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

4) tbl_exam

```
     +-------+-----+-------+-----+------+
     | class | sid | paper | MaM | ExId |
     +-------+-----+-------+-----+------+
     |    13 |   3 |     1 |  25 |   64 |
     |    13 |   1 |     1 |  25 |   64 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 |  25 |   64 |
     |    13 |   4 |     1 |  25 |   64 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  13 |   64 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  12 |   64 |
     |    13 |   7 |     1 |  25 |   64 |
     |    13 |   3 |     1 |  25 |   65 |
     |    13 |   1 |     1 |  25 |   65 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 |  25 |   65 |
     |    13 |   4 |     1 |  25 |   65 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  13 |   65 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  12 |   65 |
     |    13 |   7 |     1 |  25 |   65 |
     |    13 |   3 |     2 |  50 |   66 |
     |    13 |   1 |     1 | 100 |   66 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 | 100 |   66 |
     |    13 |   4 |     1 | 100 |   66 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  50 |   66 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  50 |   66 |
     |    13 |   7 |     1 | 100 |   66 |
     |    13 |   3 |     1 |  25 |   67 |
     |    13 |   1 |     1 |  25 |   67 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 |  25 |   67 |
     |    13 |   4 |     1 |  25 |   67 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  13 |   67 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  12 |   67 |
     |    13 |   7 |     1 |  25 |   67 |
     |    13 |   3 |     2 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   3 |     3 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   1 |     2 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   1 |     3 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 | 100 |   68 |
     |    13 |   4 |     2 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   4 |     3 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   7 |     2 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   7 |     3 |  50 |   68 |
     |    13 |   3 |     1 |  25 |   69 |
     |    13 |   1 |     1 |  25 |   69 |
     |    13 |   2 |     1 |  25 |   69 |
     |    13 |   4 |     1 |  25 |   69 |
     |    13 |   5 |     1 |  13 |   69 |
     |    13 |   6 |     1 |  12 |   69 |
     |    13 |   7 |     1 |  25 |   69 |
     |    13 |   3 |     3 |  50 |   66 |
     +-------+-----+-------+-----+------+
```

I have written a sql code to generate an output like this:

```
SELECT 
ts.subject as 'SUBJECT',
tme.exnm as 'EXAM',
tc.Marks as 'MARKS',
tc.paper as 'PAPER'
FROM
tbl_cmarks tc,
tbl_subjects ts,
tbl_masterexam tme
WHERE tc.rollno = 1 AND 
ts.id = tc.subId AND 
tme.exid = tc.Examid
```

It Produces an output Like this :

```
      +-------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+
      |      SUBJECT      |       EXAM        | MARKS | PAPER |
      +-------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+
      | ENGLISH           | Unit Test-1       |    21 |     1 |
      | తెలుగు            | Unit Test-1       |    18 |     1 |
       | हिन्दी            | Unit Test-1       |    20 |     1 |
      | MATHEMATICS       | Unit Test-1       |    23 |     1 |
      | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Unit Test-1       |    11 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Unit Test-1       |    11 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Unit Test-1       |    22 |     1 |
       | ENGLISH           | Unit Test-2       |    20 |     1 |
       | తెలుగు            | Unit Test-2       |    20 |     1 |
       | हिन्दी            | Unit Test-2       |    19 |     1 |
       | MATHEMATICS       | Unit Test-2       |    22 |     1 |
       | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Unit Test-2       |    10 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Unit Test-2       |    10 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Unit Test-2       |    20 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Unit Test-2       |    20 |     1 |
       | తెలుగు            | Quarterly Exams   |    75 |     1 |
       | हिन्दी            | Quarterly Exams   |    89 |     1 |
       | MATHEMATICS       | Quarterly Exams   |    80 |     1 |
       | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Quarterly Exams   |    45 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Quarterly Exams   |    42 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Quarterly Exams   |    89 |     1 |
       | ENGLISH           | Half yearly Exams |    41 |     2 |
       | ENGLISH           | Half yearly Exams |    35 |     3 |
       | MATHEMATICS       | Half yearly Exams |    40 |     2 |
       | MATHEMATICS       | Half yearly Exams |    45 |     3 |
       | ENGLISH           | Quarterly Exams   |    40 |     2 |
       | ENGLISH           | Quarterly Exams   |    41 |     3 |
       | ENGLISH           | Unit Test-3       |    16 |     1 |
       | తెలుగు            | Unit Test-3       |    19 |     1 |
       | MATHEMATICS       | Unit Test-3       |    20 |     1 |
       | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Unit Test-3       |    10 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Unit Test-3       |    10 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Unit Test-3       |    20 |     1 |
       | తెలుగు            | Half yearly Exams |    45 |     2 |
       | తెలుగు            | Half yearly Exams |    40 |     3 |
       | हिन्दी            | Half yearly Exams |    75 |     1 |
       | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Half yearly Exams |    40 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Half yearly Exams |    42 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Half yearly Exams |    40 |     2 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Half yearly Exams |    40 |     3 |
       | ENGLISH           | Unit Test-4       |    19 |     1 |
        | తెలుగు            | Unit Test-4       |    19 |     1 |
       | हिन्दी            | Unit Test-4       |    18 |     1 |
      | MATHEMATICS       | Unit Test-4       |    20 |     1 |
      | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | Unit Test-4       |    12 |     1 |
       | BIOLOGY           | Unit Test-4       |    11 |     1 |
       | SOCIAL STUDIES    | Unit Test-4       |    15 |     1 |
       +-------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+
```

But I want to Display the result as :

```
      +-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
      |                   |  U.T-1  |  U.T-2  |  Quart  |  U.T-3  |  Half   | U.T-4   |
      +-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
      | SUBJECT           | M Max G | M Max G | M Max G | M Max G | M Max G | M Max G |
      | ENGLISH         | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 40,45 50,50 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      |  తెలుగు           | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      |  हिन्दी           | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      | MATHEMATICS       | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      | PHYSICAL SCIENCES | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      | BIOLOGY           | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      | SOCIAL STUDIES    | 21 25 A | 21 25 A | 85 100 A | 21 25 A | 45,40 50,50 A | 21 25 A |
      +-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Please anyone tell me where should i change my query to reproduce the desired result

I have tried GROUP_CONCAT(exnm) But i am not able to get the desired result.
Please tell me / give me an idea to write the code to display like this.

Thank you.

To Display the Grade i have created a Function like this

```
      DELIMITER $$
      CREATE FUNCTION `ShowGrade`(val FLOAT(10,2)) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
      BEGIN
      DEClARE p FLOAT(10,2);    
      DEClARE g TEXT;
      set p=val;
  IF p>=91 and p<=100 THEN 
    set g= "A+";
  END IF;
  IF p>=71 and p<=90 THEN 
        set g= "A";
    END IF;
  IF p>=51 and p<=70 THEN 
    set g= "B+";
    END IF;
  IF p>=41 and p<=50 THEN 
    set g= "B";
    END IF;
  IF p>=0 and p<=40 THEN 
    set g= "C";
    END IF;
      return g;
     END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
         CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN examid = ''', exid,
         ''' THEN marks END) `', exnm, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM tbl_masterexam
 WHERE cid = 13;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.subject, ', @sql, 
                  '  FROM tbl_Cmarks m JOIN Tbl_subjects s 
                       ON m.subid = s.id 
                    WHERE m.rollno = 1
                      AND m.cid = 13
                    GROUP BY m.subid, s.subject');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
|           SUBJECT | UNIT TEST-1 | UNIT TEST-2 | QUARTERLY EXAMS | UNIT TEST-3 | HALF YEARLY EXAMS | UNIT TEST-4 | PRE - PUBLIC EXAMS |
|-------------------|-------------|-------------|-----------------|-------------|-------------------|-------------|--------------------|
|             తెలుగు |          18 |          20 |              75 |          19 |                45 |          19 |             (null) |
|               हिन्दी |          20 |          19 |              89 |      (null) |                75 |          18 |             (null) |
|           ENGLISH |          21 |          20 |              41 |          16 |                41 |          19 |             (null) |
|       MATHEMATICS |          23 |          22 |              80 |          20 |                45 |          20 |             (null) |
| PHYSICAL SCIENCES |          11 |          10 |              45 |          10 |                40 |          12 |             (null) |
|           BIOLOGY |          11 |          10 |              42 |          10 |                42 |          11 |             (null) |
|    SOCIAL STUDIES |          22 |          20 |              89 |          20 |                40 |          15 |             (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9530e/1)** demo

Comment: @Narendar_CH IS it what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes sir this is the output i am trying to achieve. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I want to show comma separated Marks for those Exams Having Paper Column 2,3. where should i modify this script to do so

Comment: sir the result structure is changed, Is this possible to get the result like i mentioned /edited ?

Comment: Could you help me, please.

Comment: @Narendar_CH Can you please elaborate a bit what M and Max` are? Also what sid is in tbl_exam? What value you use to calculate grade? How does `paper` column fit in the picture?

Comment: sid in tbl_exam are Subject Ids, M means Marks obtained as you already shown in the output, Max Means Max Marks for the subject in that exam, Grade is Calculated as ((M/Max)*100) the outcome should pass to ShowGrade() Function it'll result the Grade as A+/A/B+/B etc .

Comment: And paper describes that the subject for that exam have two papers, simply, suppose take a subject Id 3 (ENGLISH) in the tbl_exam for Exam Id 68(Half Yearly) has papers 2 i.e ENGLISH -1 And ENGLISH -2 and the Max Marks are 50,50 correspondingly, in the same way the marks are stored in tbl_cmarks table

Comment: To simply say if paper columns having 2 & 3 then Marks should be displayed in ',' separated like 45,40 like this

Comment: OK. How grade should be calculated when there are two or more papers?

Comment: Yes you are right sir, i did'nt get this question in mind. Can we do like this if for paper 2,3 can we make sum(Marks) and pass it to ShowGrade where the Max Marks will be Sum(MaM)

Comment: I have tried this pl look @ this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2d6e/2

Comment: At Last I am able to display the marks by Paper wise in Exams, Still Not get the Full result. look at this code http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fb17c/2 Please help me to resolve this.